# How do I retrieve a remote file and store it on the local machine on PHP (using OpenSSH/SCP)?

Tags: php, ssh, scp, openssh

as the title states, I'm having trouble with retrieving a file from a remote SSH server, through PHP.

I am able to retrieve the file through the Command Shell, but when I attempt to do so through PHP, it does not seem to work.

For example, this is how my code looks like on the PHP script:

`echo shell_exec(scp $remoteUser@$remoteIP:$remoteFilePath $localFilePath);`

For context, this PHP script is for a web page. Before the above command, I also had another SCP command (where I copy a local file to the remote server) and a SSH command, and those were able to execute successfully without any issues (the commands were executed through shell_exec() as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a lib which assists SFTP or SCP usage - for example **idct/sftp-client**: https://github.com/ideaconnect/idct-sftp-client

Include it in your project, then create an instance:

```php
use IDCT\Networking\Ssh\SftpClient;
use IDCT\Networking\Ssh\Credentials;
$client = new SftpClient();
```

Then create set up proper credentials - password or public key:

```php
# password
$credentials = Credentials::withPassword($username, $password);
$client->setCredentials($credentials);

# or key:
$credentials = Credentials::withPublicKey($username, $publicKey, $privateKey, $passphrase = null);
$client->setCredentials($credentials);
```

Then connect and download your file:

```php
$client->connect($host);

# using sftp
$client->download(ENTER_REMOTE_FILE_NAME);

# or scp
$client->scpDownload(ENTER_REMOTE_FILE_NAME);

$client->close();
```

It is much more elegant than using less secure and system dependent `shell_exec`. You can use also all the methods youself: `ssh2_scp_recv`, `ssh2_connect` etc.

Comment: The reason behind why I was using `shell_exec()` was that I was using OpenSSH for the SSH communications between the local and remote machines.

Would the above-mentioned methods (eg: `ssh2_connect`) be able to be used with OpenSSH, or would I need to look for an alternative SSH server/client utility?

Comment: php's SSH lib also uses OpenSSH for communication: you can point to the same identity (key) file. If you still prefer to use shell_exec etc. be sure to remember that if you open the PHP file using a webserver then usually you access it with a different user (for example `nginx` or `www-data` etc.) therefore you should set keys for such user in addition to the one you use normally.

Comment: Ah I see, since PHP's SSH lib also uses OpenSSH, I don't mind trying out the above-mentioned methods which you have suggested!

Regarding php's SSH lib (is it SSH2?), do you have any recommended resources which I could refer towards to aid me in changing my code to use it instead of `shell_exec`?

Comment: Exactly, the lib is called "ssh2". You can install it on debian based systems usually by typing `apt-get install php7-ssh2` or `apt-get install php-ssh2` etc. Pure usage, connection and download is documented nicely in PHP's docs: for example https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-recv.php / If you do not want to use the mentioned above lib and only pure php-ssh2 then I would say that a good start is to check internally which methods it uses for respective methods. Yet I still suggest using it, it has few contributors and was even used by `thephpleague`for a while.

Comment: Sorry for asking more questions haha, but is the "ssh2" library available (or rather, able to be installed) on Windows? This is because I'm running the php website on a Windows machine, using XAMPP.

In addition to that, the remote machines that I'm accessing does include a Windows machine as well, along with an Ubuntu machine.

Thanks for the help/answers so far, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure, you can get it from PHP's website: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/1.2/ download a version respective to your php version (64 or 32 bit, NTS or TS [most likely you are using NTS version but you can check that with `phpinfo()`). Then place the dll file in your php's extensions dir. It may be for example `c:\tools\php74\ext` or `c:\php\` and enable it in the `php.ini` which should be in the PHP's folder by adding line `extension=php_ssh2.dll` under the `Dynamic Extensions` section of the file (search for existing `extension=` in the file).

Comment: I’ll look more into it and attempt to implement it, with the help of the resources you’ve provided! Thank you for the helpful answers, and I hope you have a good day ahead! :)